# Flag a comment on deleted answer

Tags: support, flags, comments, comment-flags

Why Stack Overflow allowing to flag a comment on deleted answer? Is it correct functionality?

And why stack overflow does not providing **success message** after completion of flag?

Comment: _Why Stack Overflow allowing to flag a comment on deleted answer?_ because mod flag is by definition used to handle exceptional cases and scenarios(hope I got the word usage right?). You may need to report some weird behavior even if OP deletes post

Comment: @SurajRao Ok. understood. But what about the success message after a flag?

Comment: guys! Could you please let me know the reason for down vote?

Comment: I expect people to go off on the success message as that would not be welcomed if it would exist. Also asking *why* questions without any explanation or reasoning what bothers you about it and why it is important the question is asked and gets an answer. At least that explains my down vote.

Comment: @RameshRajendran: as with all your other bug reports / support questions on meta: votes on meta tend to indicate whether people agree or not. I'd have assumed you'd got that by now, considering your history of questions on here.

Answer (score 12):

Why shouldn't it be allowed? Deleted posts can be edited so it makes sense to allow flags on comments as well. So yes, it is correct functionality.

I have seen enough case where a rude post was accompanied by plenty of rude and abusive comments. The post gets deleted with red flags to have its content hidden from casual viewing, leaving the comments.

Now you could argue that on red flagged posts, all comments should be nuked as well but that would also wipe possible guidance that was given in comments and as authors can see their own deleted posts (and comments) they might want to revisit, edit and then flag to have it undeleted. In which case it is better that the stale comments have been removed by them.

There is a success message after completion of the flag. Once you flagged a comment you can't flag it again and if you go to your profile you'll see your pending flags, including the comment flags you currently raised. If you flag a rude or abusive comment (or a comment with certain catch phrases in it) it might get instantly deleted which is another form of feedback.

If you're really looking for a pop-up message, specially one that you have to dismiss, then no such thing exists and before you even ask: No, that is not something that should be added as it would extremely annoying and hurt the speed at which you want to flag those comments (we're already throttled to a comment flag every 5 seconds). So don't go posting a feature request for that, you'll be down voted into oblivion (and you seem to care about down votes on meta).