# how can see removed users data?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, users

Is it possible to see removed user list?   how can see removed users list? or is there any reputation level to see that list?

Comment: That data isn't available to you.

Comment: @bluefeet  Then who can see that data?

Comment: @RameshRajendran moderators and employees (who have a diamond next to their names)

Comment: If am asked a small doubt. automatically down voted start.

Comment: @RameshRajendran: You're being downvoted because people don't want regular people to see the list of removed users.

Comment: If you're alluding to the fact that you get downvoted as soon as you ask a question, you should probably ask yourself why that keeps happening.

Comment: @RameshRajendran: People disagree with your feature request. You should be familiar with [how downvotes on meta work](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) by now, considering your history of unpopular feature requests / bug reports.

Comment: @Cerbrus: [Where have I heard you say that before?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360654/flag-a-comment-on-deleted-answer#comment539898_360654)

Comment: @BoltClock: nice, _someone_ remembered!

Comment: As for all other posts you made in meta: are you just coming here as soon as you go 'hey could the site do this?' Or do you properly think about the pros and cons. What would be the benefit of seeing this list? None.

Answer (score 16):

You can't.

That data is not accessible to ordinary users and wouldn't (& shouldn't) be given out even if you asked for it.

Answer (score 1):

Using Data Explorer, one can get some information on deleted users: see [Top Deleted Users](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/768896/top-deleted-users-with-dates-of-first-and-last-posts) query.

Their reputation is practically impossible to recalculate, but the total score of their posts is a good proxy for that (multiply it by 10 and you'll get the approximate amount of reputation they would have). The top 1000 deleted Stack Overflow users are sorted by the date of their last post, most recent first.

Exception: "anon" is the name given by the systems to the posts that were disassociated from the owner, so that entry of the table is fake in the sense that it does not reflect a single user.

Of the recent deletions, the one with highest score is user34537 otherwise known as acidzombie24. The all-time record is held by user529758 otherwise known as H2CO3.